# Printing out elements of array located in dynamic memory

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc

XXX----Yep, its a Homework problem, but yea I'm stuck. Why doesn't this print out the elements of the array? Please help---XXX

Ok, we got the printing out part figured out. Thank you so much. Now the problem is the only the first character(s) before the space delimiter gets put into the array. I need all the words or characters to be set into the array.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int size = 0;
    char **array = malloc(0); //malloc for dynamic memory since the input size is unknown
    static const char filename[] = "input.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        char line [ 128 ]; 

        char delims[] = " ";
        char *result = NULL;
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)  {
            result = strtok(line, delims); //separate by space
            size++;
            array = realloc(array, size * sizeof (char*)); //declare array with unknown size
            array[size - 1] = result;

        }
        fclose(file);
    } else {
        perror(filename);
    }
    return 0;
    printf(array); //print array???
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code. I believe that it does what you are expecting.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int size = 0;
    int i;
    char **array = malloc(0); //malloc for dynamic memory since the input size is unknown

    static const char filename[] = "input.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file != NULL) 
    {
        char line [ 128 ]; 

        char delims[] = " ";
        char *result = NULL;

        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
        {
            result = strtok(line, delims); //separate by space

            while( result != NULL ) 
            {                       
                size++;

                array = realloc(array, size * sizeof (char*)); //declare array with unknown size
                array[size - 1] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));  // allocate memory for 100 chars
                strcpy(array[size - 1], result);               // copy the result

                result = strtok( NULL, delims );
            }
        }

        fclose(file);
    } 
    else 
    {
        perror(filename);
    }

    // return 0; 

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%d] = %s\n", i, array[i]);
    }

    // printf(array); //print array???

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is C. You can't just call printf() and expect it to do the work for you.  You need to iterate through the array with a for() or while() loop and print out each element.

Assuming it is an array of strings:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    printf("array[%d] = %s\n", i, array[i]);
```

Comment: I tried for(int i=0;i<5;printf("%d ",array[i]), i++); Doesnt work.

Comment: @MarlonBrando: That is not valid C. You have to declare `int i;` at the top of your function, then use `for(i=0;...)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But now it only prints out the first element that is the first character(s) before a space

Comment: `%d` is for printing signed integers. Use `%s` for strings.

Comment: @Dennis the %d only prints out the index number. %s is right there, if you read a bit farther

Comment: Still cant figure out why does it only print the first element. I think it only puts the first element in the array

Comment: @MarlonBrando Check the behaviour of `strtok` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/please-help-in-strtok).

Comment: @MarlonBrando: I know that `%s` is right. That is why I said *use `%s` for strings.*

Comment: @bacchus I believe I'm using strtok correctly. I think I'm not assigning it to the array in the right way