# Use strtok in a for loop

Tags: c

To loop over a string str I used:

```
for (tok = strtok(str, ";"); tok && *tok; tok = strtok(NULL, ";"))  
{  
   //do stuff  
}
```

I would like to understand how this loop works. It seems to me:

```
(1) tok = strtok(str, ";"); //initialization of tok with the first token in str    
(2) tok = strtok(NULL, ";"); // go to the next token in str? how does this work? 
(3) tok && *tok;  //this stops the loop when tok =NULL or *tok=NULL
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: You're right on all the three counts :)

Comment: Take a look at the **Related** questions for more details about how `strtok()` works. Especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/please-help-in-strtok?rq=1

Comment: The `*tok` test isn't part of the standard strtok idiom. It looks like it wants to stop early on an empty field, but it won't work because strtok skips empty fields.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley So *tok is useless it should be removed? Thanks

Comment: It's not doing anything. Removing `&& *tok` will not change the behavior. If you want to detect empty fields, you can't use strtok.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample strtok implementation: http://bxr.su/o/lib/libc/string/strtok.c#strtok

As you see in the code, it uses a static character pointer internally (pretty much every version I've seen store a pointer, either as a global variable or as a static variable as in the case above).  This version calls the reentrant `strtok_r` (and the side effect of the line `if (s == NULL && (s = *last) == NULL)`
 is to use the last pointer if NULL is passed)

Comment: "pretty much every version I've seen" -- it isn't possible to implement it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> (2) tok = strtok(NULL, ";"); // go to the next token in str? how does this work?

That's exactly how `strtok()` works. By sending `NULL` as the first parameter, you signal that `strtok()` should continue with the string which was sent to it during the last call. If you want to know the exact implementation details, you will need to look at the source code for `strtok()`. Most likely it uses a static local variable.

Comment: The way it works is indeed that it squirrels away the first argument from the initial call in a private variable.

Comment: Actually, I should have said that squirrels away the end of the first token / start of the next token, and updates that with each call.

Answer (score -1):

if you read the `manpages` for `strtok` it states

> The  strtok() function parses a string into a sequence of tokens.  On
>   the first call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified
>   in str.  In each subsequent call that should parse the same string,
>   str should be NULL.

Answer (score -1):

You can find more about [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) here.  It has some examples of how to use it.

Quoting from the link, the `str` parameter in `strtok(str, delim)`:

> Notice that the contents of this string are modified and broken into smaller strings (tokens).
>   Alternativelly, a null pointer may be specified, in which case the function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.

Your 3 guesses are correct.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it just duplicates what the OP wrote, except for "how does this work?", which it doesn't answer.