# Split String by Carriage Return C

Tags: c, string, split, httprequest, webproxy

I am having a problem where I am trying to split an HTTP request by a carriage return for a web proxy.  The request does not seem to split.

Here is an example request:
GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.w3.org\r\n

My attempt is:

```
char* split_request;
split_request = strtok(request, "\r\n");
```

But it never gets split?  I am not sure what I am missing.  It seems to split when I am using wget or the browser to test the web proxy, but doesn't with telnet.

Comment: You seem to assume this is C's variant of `split` in other languages; it is not. `strtok` scans for *any* character in its argument string.

Answer (score 10):

Are you doing this way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char str[] = "GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.w3.org\r\n";
    char* pch = NULL;

    pch = strtok(str, "\r\n");

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1   
Host: www.w3.org
```

Comment: This is clearly not C. Tempted to downvote, except that your string handling is correct.

Comment: I overlooked the header files iostream and cstring. Edited it now.

Answer (score 3):

Check the below link:

[How does strtok() split the string into tokens in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/how-does-strtok-split-the-string-into-tokens-in-c)

```
int main()
{
    char request[20]="some\r\nstring";
    char* split_request;
    split_request = strtok(request,"\r\n");
    while(split_request != NULL)
    {
       printf("%s\n",split_request);
       split_request = strtok(NULL,"\r\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```