# Parsing CSV Values in C

Tags: c, csv

I am trying to write a basic CSV parser in C that generates a dynamic array of `char*` when given a `char*` and a separator character, such as a comma:

```
char **filldoc_parse_csv(char *toparse, char sepchar)
{
    char **strings = NULL;

    char *buffer = NULL;

    int j = 0;
    int k = 1;

    for(int i=0; i < strlen(toparse); i++)
    {
        if(toparse[i] != sepchar)
        {
            buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(char)*k);
            strcat(buffer, (const char*)toparse[i]);
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            strings = realloc(strings, sizeof(buffer)+1);

            strings[j] = buffer;

            free(buffer);

            j++;

        }
    }

    return strings;


}
```

However, when I call the function as in the manner below:

`char **strings = filldoc_parse_csv("hello,how,are,you", ',');`

I end up with a segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcat_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcat.S:166
166 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcat.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __strcat_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcat.S:166
#1  0x000000000040072c in filldoc_parse_csv (toparse=0x400824 "hello,how,are,you", sepchar=44 ',') at filldocparse.c:20
#2  0x0000000000400674 in main () at parsetest.c:6
```

The problem is centered around allocating enough space for the buffer string. If I have to, I will make buffer a static array, however, I would like to use dynamic memory allocation for this purpose. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Personally I would be using `strtok` to do this, as splitting strings is why it exists in the first place.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/how-does-strtok-split-the-string-into-tokens-in-c

Comment: CSV files are *deceptively* simple to parse, and I mean deceptively in the very worst case because there are so many corner-cases and other things that needs special handling.

Comment: You can just change the separator in *scanf() functions from white space to commas or whatever else you wish.  strsep() and strtok() have some nasty side effects that you may wish to avoid.

Comment: @technosaurus I wouldn't call the side-effects of [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) *nasty*, one just have to know that it will modify the source string and that it can't handle empty fields.

Comment: Just make a backup of the input string that `strtok` will be working with. You'll get a segfault if you're passed a readonly string. I put an example in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various problems

1. `strcat(buffer, (const char*)toparse[i]);` attempts to changes a `char` to a string.
2. `strings = realloc(strings, sizeof(buffer)+1);` reallocates the same amount of space.  `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the pointer `buffer`, not the size of memory it points to.
3. The calling function has no way to know how many entries in `strings`. Suggest andding a `NULL` sentinel.

Minor: better to use `size_t` rather than `int`.  Use more descriptive names.  Do not re-call `strlen(toparse)` repetitively. Use `for(int i=0; toparse[i]; i++)`  .  Make `toparse` a `const char *`

Answer (score 2):

You have problems with your memory allocations. When you do e.g. `sizeof(buffer)` you will get the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to. That means you will in the first run allocate five bytes (on a 32-bit system), and the next time the function is called you will allocate five bytes *again*.

There are also many other problems, like you freeing the `buffer` pointer once you assigned the pointer to `strings[j]`. The problem with this is that the assignment only copies the pointer and not what it points to, so by freeing `buffer` you also free `strings[j]`.

Both the above problems will lead to your program having [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which is the most common cause of runtime-crashes.

You should also avoid assigning the result of `realloc` to the pointer you're trying to reallocate, because if `realloc` fails it will return `NULL` and you loose the original pointer causing a memory leak.