# Storing as using result of strtok in array in C

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to split the input from `fgets` using `strtok`, and store the results in an array, i.e. `newArgs`, so I can then call `execvp` and essentially execute the input passed by `fgets`.

E.g. `ls -la` will map to `/bin/ls -la` and execute correctly.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char buff[1024];
    fgets(buff, 1024, stdin);
    buff[strcspn(buff, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buff);
    printf("%d\n", strlen(buff));
    char *newArgs[30];
    char *token;
    char delim[2] = " ";
    token = strtok(buff, delim);
    int i = 0;
    while(token != NULL) 
    {
        if(newArgs[i])
        {
            sprintf(newArgs[i], "%s", token);
            printf("%s\n", newArgs[i]); 
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        i++;
    }
    execvp(newArgs[0], newArgs);

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting a Segmentation fault, even though I'm checking the existence of `newArgs[i]`, which is a little odd. Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: Char pointers are not strings, and uninitialized arrays have random values.

Comment: `newArgs` isn't actually initialized when you try to access it. You've allocated 30 `char` pointers in the array, but nothing for each individual index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does strtok() split the string into tokens in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/how-does-strtok-split-the-string-into-tokens-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems I see:

1. You are using uninitialized values of `newArgs[i]`. You have:

   ```
   char *newArgs[30];
   ```

   This is an array of uninitialized pointers. Then, you go on to use them as:

   ```
   if(newArgs[i])
   ```

   That is cause for undefined behavior. You can fix that by initializing the pointers to NULL.

   ```
   char *newArgs[30] = {};
   ```
2. You haven't allocated memory for `newArgs[i]` before calling

   ```
   sprintf(newArgs[i], "%s", token);
   ```

   That is also cause for undefined behavior. You can fix that by using:

   ```
   newArgs[i] = strdup(token);
   ```
3. The list of arguments being passed to `execvp` must contains a NULL pointer.

   From http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp (emphasis mine):

   > The **`execv()`**, **`execvp()`**, and **`execvpe()`** functions provide an array of pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the new program. The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed. **The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.**

   You are missing the last requirement. You need o make sure that one of the elements of `newArgs` is a NULL pointer. This problem will go away if you initialize the pointers to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating any memory for each element of `newArgs`. Try using a multi-dimensional array, like `newArgs[30][100]`. Don't forget to ensure they're null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating memory for `newArgs` before storing it in the string.
Add

```
    newArgs[i] = malloc(strlen(token));
```

before the `if` statement inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to copy the tokens you are finding in `buff`.

That won't always be the case, but it certainly is here: `buff` is not modified before the `execvp` and `execvp` doesn't return. Knowing when not to copy a C string is not as useful as knowing how to copy a C string, but both are important.

Not copying the strings will simplify the code considerably. All you need to do is fill in the array of strings which you will pass to `execvp`:

```
 char* args[30]; /* Think about dynamic allocation instead */
 char** arg = &args[0];
 *arg = strtok(buff, " ");
 while (*arg++) {
   /* Should check for overflow of the args array */
   *arg = strtok(NULL, " ");
 }
 execvp(args[0], args);
```

Note that the above code will store the NULL returned by `strtok` at the end of the `args` array. This is required by `execvp`, which needs to know where the last arg is.