# C file compiling but not running

Tags: c

So my program takes a file as input and parses out spaces.  Tokens are saved into an array. I have a function to print out the contents of the array to test if the parser works.  The code compiles with gcc -o filename filename.c .  But when I run the program and give it a filepath, I get a pop up window indicating filename.exe has stopped working : A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.  Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char file_name[100];
char *token_array[256];
int main()
{
   char ch;
   FILE *fp;

   int n=0;
   char *str;

   printf("Enter filepath\n");
   gets(file_name);

   fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); 

   if( fp == NULL )
   {
      perror("Error opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   int i = 0;         
   char *p; 
   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
   {
    char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);
    p = strtok(str, " ");
    i=0;

    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(token_array[i], p);
    }

    i++;

   }

   for(n=0;n<256;n++)
   {
      printf("%s", &token_array[n]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is obviously about programming.  It's just that it's apparently from a novice programmer trying to learn C, and who is getting no help from the almost-useless Windows error popup dialog.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  You should have gotten a warning that `gets()` is depreciated (and completely removed in C11)  There are a number of lesser warnings that will also be output by the compiler having to do with implicit conversion of numeric values.  `For `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line  2) consistently indent the code.  Never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{'.  Un indent before every closing brace '}'.  4 spaces is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and is easy for the human eye to recognize.

Comment: this code block: `   while(p!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(token_array[i], p);
    }`  is not incrementing the variable `i`, so all the tokens are placed at the same offset into the array: `token_array[]`.

Comment: this code sequence: ` while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
   {
    char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);` will toss away the first character of every line in the file.

Comment: this line: `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);` is nonsence.  your declaring a `char *` as what the function: `fgets()` returns, but your not assigning that pointer to any variable.  Strongly suggest removing the call to `fgetc()` and place the call to `fgets()` in its' place

Comment: to save yourself lots of 'gray hairs' in the future (because the error of only typing one `=` rather than two: `==` changes the comparison in to an assignment, not what you usually want for lines like: `if( fp == NULL )`  Strongly suggest getting into the habit of placing the literal on the left, I.E. `if(  NULL == fp )` so if you happen to only type a single `=`, the compiler will catch the error immediately, rather than you spending hours and  hours debugging the code.

Comment: the token array is declared as 256 pointers to char arrays.  However, this line: `strcpy(token_array[i], p);` is trying to copy characters over those pointers.  Strongly suggest using: `token_array[i] = strdup(p);`

Comment: the file is being read, 1) read first char of a line 2) read the rest of the line, However, after reading a line, the call to `strtok()` needs (on the first call with the new line) to be: `p = strtok( str, " " );`  then, in a loop, p = strtok( NULL, " " );`  so this code block: `while(p!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(token_array[i], p);
    }` should be: `while( i < 256 && p != NULL ) { token_array[i] = strdup(p);  i++;  p = strtok( NULL, " " );  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code instead. I changed your program so that it can read and tokenize the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *trim(char *s) {
    int i = strlen(s) - 1;
    if (s[i] == '\n')
        s[i] = '\0';
    return s;
}

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100
char *token_array[256];
int main( int argc, char** argv ){

    const char *delimiter_characters = " ";
    char *filename =  malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter filepath\n");
    fgets(filename, 100, stdin);


    FILE *input_file = fopen( trim(filename), "r" );
    char buffer[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
    char *last_token;

    if( input_file == NULL ){

        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", filename );

    }else{

        // Read each line into the buffer
        while( fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, input_file) != NULL ){

            // Write the line to stdout
            //fputs( buffer, stdout );

            // Gets each token as a string and prints it
            last_token = strtok( buffer, delimiter_characters );
            while( last_token != NULL ){
                //printf( "%s\n", last_token );
                token_array[i] = malloc(100);
                strcpy(token_array[i], last_token);
                i++;
                last_token = strtok( NULL, delimiter_characters );
            }

        }

        if( ferror(input_file) ){
            perror( "The following error occurred" );
        }

        fclose( input_file );

    }
    int n;
    for(n=0;token_array[n] != NULL && n<256;n++)
    {
        printf("%s", token_array[n]);
        free(token_array[n]);
    }
    free(filename);
    return 0;

}
```

**data.txt**

```
Hello Foo Bar
How are you?
```

**Test**

```
Debug/gnu
Enter filepath
data.txt
HelloFooBar
Howareyou?
Process finished with exit code 0
```

The contents of the array are

```
n[0] Hello
n[1] Foo
n[2] Bar

n[3] How
n[4] are
n[5] you?
```

You can see the contents of the array if you add debug info:

`printf("n[%d] %s\n", n, token_array[n]);`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems to put "HelloFooBar" into a[0] and "Howareyou?" into a[1].  But I want Hello to be a[0], Foo to be a[1].

Comment: @user3002315 I updated my answer to show you that Hello is the first element and Foo is the second element. It think it should be what you want if you try it.

Comment: Just a note, in `trim` in `if ((i > 0) && (s[i] == '\n'))`, the check for `(i > 0)` isn't necessary, if `strlen` returns `0`, `s[0]` is already `0` and there is no harm done setting `s[0] = '\0';` Your call.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I now made the changes you suggested and added calls to `free`(without recompiling and when I make changes without recompiling I usually break my code...)

Comment: @Programmer400 if I wanted to add tab and newline as delimiters as well, is there a quick fix?

Comment: @user3002315 Yes, just change the `delimiter` to several: `const char *delimiter_characters = " \n\t";`

Answer (score 1):

This line does nothing:

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);
```

As written, that line is nothing but a declaration of a function, probably not what you want.

If you're going to use `fgets()`, use `fgets()` alone and don't mix it with `fgetc()`:

```
char str[1024];
while ( fgets( str, sizeof( str ), fp )
{
   .
   .
   .
```

`fgets()` returns `NULL` upon `EOF` or an error condition.  And note that `str` is not a `char *`, it's a `char` array.  An even better solution would be to use `getline()` because `fgets()` with a fixed-length buffer can only read entire lines that fit into the buffer.  Longer lines will be split.

`fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  But you don't shouldn't use `fgetc()` when reading lines from a file with `fgets()`.  Pick one and use that.  But if you use `fgetc()`, you'll need to write code to put together each line as you read it character-by-character.

And what does `token_array[i]` point to?  You declare `token_array` as an array of pointers:

```
char *token_array[256];
```

But you never allocate any memory for each pointer in the array to point to.

The easiest solution is to change

```
strcpy(token_array[i], p);
```

to

```
token_array[i] = strdup(p);
```

assuming your platform has `strdup()`, which is equivalent to a `malloc()` and `strcpy()` to the memory returned by `malloc()`, so you need to call `free()` on the string you get from `strdup()`.

Your use of `strtok()` is wrong.  See [How does strtok() split the string into tokens in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/how-does-strtok-split-the-string-into-tokens-in-c) for examples of proper `strtok()` usage.

And since `token_array` is an array of `char *` pointers, this

```
printf("%s", &token_array[n]);
```

will take the address of the actual pointer itself, and not the string it's supposed to point to.  It will then try to print out a "string" in the memory containing the pointer variable.  That's won't work well.  Since it's already a `char *`, all you need is this:

```
printf("%s", token_array[n]);
```

Comment: I tried the code, and I also needed to trim the filename, since it reads a newline that is not part of the filename (please look at my answer for details).

Comment: I tried your suggestions, and now my control prompt is just frozen.  Is there an infinite loop somewhere?