# Why I need to use NULL pointer when using strtok() in C?

Tags: c, string, null, strtok

First my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100]="nahin bin kaysar";
    char *space;

    space = strtok(str," ");
    while(space != NULL) {
        space = strtok(NULL," ");
        puts(space);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know this program will split the string into three different parts. Before the loop I split the first word and assigned to the string `space`. But my question is why I had to use`NULL` pointer inside the loop as a parameter of the `strtok()` function. I have searched it for hours and no answer satisfied my needs.

Comment: Read the docs?  (e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)

Comment: This means continuing processing. Also `space = strtok(NULL," ");puts(space);` --> `puts(space);space = strtok(NULL," ");`

Comment: a) don't use `strtok()` in new code, there's a reason for [`strsep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html). b) What's unclear about `strtok()`? It internally stores tokenization context, so if you call it with `strtok(NULL, ...)`, it continues to operate on the most recent string.

Comment: It is a confusing call because strtok() maintains internal state in statics - something that  makes it difficult to understand how subsequent calls work at all, (unless in multithreaded code, in which case they don't:).

Comment: Your code is broken and it can crash, also, what part is unclear from [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)?

Comment: `NULL` informs `strtok()` to continue tokenizing from where it last stopped.  A non-`NULL` value says to start anew.

Comment: Beware confusion between "string", "array", and "pointer". `space` in your code is not a string: it's a pointer (pointing to (parts of) an array (each part being a string after strtok changed the array contents)).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.24.5.8, P4 (*emphasis mine*)

> The `strtok` function then searches from there for a character that is contained in the
>   current separator string. If no such character is found, the current token extends to the
>   end of the string pointed to by `s1`, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null
>   pointer. **If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character, which
>   terminates the current token. The `strtok` function saves a pointer to the following
>   character, from which the next search for a token will start.**

and P5,

> **Each subsequent call, with a null pointer as the value of the first argument, starts
>   searching from the saved pointer** [...]

So, this is a feature which enables `strtok()` to continue parsing the *leftover* of the initially supplied string.

To put it in other words, an input string, containing multiple instances of the delimiter can be parsed using a simple loop using this feature. For example, if a "sentence" is to be tokenized based on the "whitespace"s to separate out each "word" , then, after the first call, a simple loop, calling `strtok()` with `NULL` as first argument will make use of internal save pointer and require less explicit effort to manage the remainder of the actual sentence.

Without this feature, manual effort would have been required to keep a tab of the *progress* made in search of the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read again the [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) and make sure you understand each parameter and the return.

Second, your code is broken, at certain point `puts` will use NULL as argument and it'll crash, you could fix it like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[100] = "nahin bin kaysar";
    const char s[2] = " ";
    char *token;

    token = strtok(str, s);
    printf("%s", token);
    while (token != NULL) {
        puts(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In any case, if you have questions after reading carefully the documentation this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/how-does-strtok-split-the-string-into-tokens-in-c) maybe can help you out.