# How to read specific column of csv in C

Tags: c, algorithm, file, csv

I have an csv file and I want to get 2nd column's data. it is like that:

```
 1st row:    4   8   6
 2nd row:    3   2   2
 3rd row:    7   7   5
```

I will add them into AVLTREE but main problem is how to get specially 2nd column's data? They delimited with semicolon.

```
4;8;6;
3;2;2;
7;7;5;
```

So far I have just this code

```
int main()
{
int c;
char buffer[1000];
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if(f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error can't open file \n");
}
while (fgets(buffer,1000,f) != NULL)
{
    char *p = strtok(buffer, ";");
    while(p)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p);
        p=strtok(NULL, ";");
    }

    printf("%c",c);
}
fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: read each line at a time, and use strtok

Comment: so you want to read 8 2 7?

Comment: Look into `fgets` and `strtok`.

Comment: Yes, exactly 8 2 7

Comment: "So far I have this code" which does absolutely nothing. SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: [Tons of duplicates here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+read+a+csv+into+a+struct+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: I have updated the code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parse CSV in C, I can advice you to use library.
I'm using this one, and it work perfectly : https://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvparser/

If moreover you want to do it by yourself, I advice you to check the strtok function : http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/strtok.3.html
This function takes a string and delimiter in parameters and get you the next elements that match with the delimiter.

I can also advice you to check this link if you want to use strtok : [How does strtok() split the string into tokens in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/how-does-strtok-split-the-string-into-tokens-in-c)