# How can I capitalize each word in string c program

Tags: c, string

I just code a program about string. My problem is how can I capitalize word at even number position of a string in c. My logic is a word at even can divide 2 equal 0. anyone can help me please, thank so much. here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void upper_string(char []);

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter a string to convert it into upper case\n");
    gets(string);
    upper_string(string);
    printf("The string in upper case: %s\n", string);
    return 0;
}

void upper_string(char s[]) {
    int c = 0;
    while (s[c] != '\0') {
        if (s[c] >= 'a' && s[c] <= 'z')
        {
            s[c] = s[c] - 32;
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets` use `fgets` instead. `My logic is a word at even can divide 2 equal 0` no you should use `%` (modulus) operator.

Comment: Are you saying you need to capitalize every 2nd word? You will obviously need to look for spaces then, in order to separate words, or [use `strtok`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3889992/69809).

Comment: even number position word in a string, such as hello world how are you today, so the world will be capitalized: world, are, today

Comment: You seem to be assuming that input will be ASCII.  That's not universal in C - you'd be safer using `toupper()` (in `<ctype.h>`) for the conversion.  And you'd no longer need to write your own buggy `isalpha()`.

Comment: Oh, and **never** use `gets()` - it's fundamentally unsafe.  Only accept input using functions that won't overrun the bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use space counter to keep track of the words.

if space counter is odd then capitalize the letters until you reach the next word.

Example:

```
void upper_string(char s[]) {
   int c = 0;
   int spaceCounter = 0; //First word not to be capitalized

   while (s[c] != '\0')
   {
     if ((spaceCounter %2 == 1) && s[c] >= 'a' && s[c] <= 'z')
     {
        s[c] = s[c] - 32; // You can use toupper function for the same.
     }
     else if(s[c] == ' ')
     {
        spaceCounter++; //Reached the next word
     }
     c++;
  }
}
```