# User csv search in C (auth)

Tags: c, csv, authentication

I need to have an auth in a .csv file, mi `users.csv` file looks like this:

```
1,root,root,1
2,user,user,0
```

The columns represents [id,user,pass,isAdmin]

What I need is to search in the .csv rows in the columns [user, pass] to check if it's equal to the user and pass entered by the user, btw, I'm using an struct in this way

### My code

```
struct User {
    int id;
    char user[20];
    char password[20];
    bool isAdmin;
};
```

And a function in this way:

```
void getUser (struct User *currentUser, FILE *users) {
    char allUsers[100][20];
    char user[20];
    char password[20];
    printf("Gimme your username: ");
    scanf("%s", user);
    printf("Gimme your password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    char line[MAX_USER_ROW_LENGTH];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), users)) {
        char *token = strtok(line, DELIMITER);
        char *token2 = strtok(line, DELIMITER);
        token2 = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);
        while (token != NULL) {
            if ((strcmp(user, token) == 0) && strcmp(password, token2) == 0) {
                printf("user an pass correct");
                
                /**
                 * here goes the code that initialize the user, i plan to do something like, if the user and pass 
                 * are correct i would do something like this:
                 *      currentUser->id = id;
                 *      currentUser->user = user;
                 *      currentUser->password = password;
                 *      currentUser->isAdmin = 1 or 0
                 *      
                 * I just relize that i have no idea how to initialize the user, sorry :c
                 * */
            } else {
                printf("user and pass not found");
                return;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);
            token2 = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);
        }
    }
}
```

### I've tried

I've used the function `strtok()` to separate each row between the commas, but, I can only compare the username or the password, not twice at each iteration, **(sorry if the wile is empty, every ting i've tried, i did ctrl+z because i entered in panic)**.

Once i've checked if the user exists and can in, i should pass the values to the `*currentUser`, but i think i can do it.

Thank you if you can help me.

Comment: *I've used the function `strtok()`*. Please show the code that does that. The empty loop suggests you would like the code provided for you. A function argument is `struct User *currentUser` which isn't used. Please show how you use that too.

Comment: I just edited the code, sorry if it doesn't make sense or something like that, it's a college homework assignment, its, just my professor just thow the "chamba", (we say chamba to work in mexico) with just a tiny explanation about files and structs and i have no idea wehre to start :c

Comment: Hm, you can't apply `strtok(line, DELIMITER);` twice to the same string. It alters the string, and is not reentrant. So effectively the second one `char *token2 = strtok(line, DELIMITER);` is like doing `char *token2 = strtok(token, DELIMITER);` but then, subsequent calls which pass `NULL` aren't going to do what you think. I suggest finding examples of how `strtok()` should be used. Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/how-does-strtok-split-the-string-into-tokens-in-c) can help.

Comment: Is there a better way to to the auth without using the `strtok()` function?

Comment: Use `strchr()` to search for your delimiter.  What is your question?

Comment: Also you wan to supply us with a program not snippets that we have to assemble and write glue code to execute.  In case there is no `main()` so we don't know how to handle errors.  `MAX_USER_ROW_LENGTH` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you use `struct User` with an `char user[20]` attribute (i.e. duplication) it's a hint that your model is incorrect.  In this case I renamed the attribute to `name`.
2. Use symbolic constants instead of magic values in your struct definition.  You can subsequently use these constants when defining related variables.
3. The `getUser()` interface doesn't have a good way to tell caller if the lookup succeeded.  On the other hand, I think it's a good choice to pass in a `FILE *users` instead of  path name.
4. Always use a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflows.  The `str()` macro that relies on the `str2()` macro is handy for this.
5. It's generally a good idea to separate user interaction and application logic.  Moved the user prompts to `main()`.
6. (Not fixed) "Gimme" is not proper English.  "User? " and "Password? " would be suitable prompts.  I assume you are not a native speaker.
7. You need `MAX_USER_ROW_LENGTH` because you use `fget()`.  If you use `getline()` instead it will allocate a suitable string for you.
8. `strtok()` modifies its input so you cannot call it twice on the same input as you do.  Prefer `strpbrk()` or `strchr()` to `strtok()`.  The `scanf()` family of functions is a concise way of parsing your file.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DELIMITER ','
#define FIELDS 4
#define NAME_LEN 19
#define PASSWORD_LEN 19
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

struct User {
    int id;
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    char password[PASSWORD_LEN+1];
    bool isAdmin;
};

struct User *getUser(FILE *users, const char *name, const char *password) {
    struct User *user = malloc(sizeof *user);
    if(!user) {
        perror("malloc");
        return NULL;
    }
    char *lineptr = NULL;
    size_t n;
    while(getline(&lineptr, &n, users) != -1) {
        int isAdmin;
        int rv = sscanf(lineptr,
            "%d,"
            "%" str(NAME_LEN) "[^,],"
            "%" str(PASSWORD_LEN) "[^,],"
            "%d",
            &user->id,
            user->name,
            user->password,
            &isAdmin
        );
        user->isAdmin = isAdmin;
        if(rv != FIELDS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d of %d fields read\n", rv, FIELDS);
            goto err;
        }
        if(
            !strcmp(name, user->name) &&
            !strcmp(password, user->password)
        ) {
            free(lineptr);
            return user;
        }
    }
err:
    free(lineptr);
    free(user);
    return NULL;
}

void printUser(struct User *user) {
    if(!user)
        return;
    printf(
        "id: %d, user: %s, password: %s, isAdmin: %d\n",
        user->id, user->name, user->password, user->isAdmin
    );
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *users = fopen("users.csv", "r");
    if(!users) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    printf("Gimme your username: ");
    scanf("%" str(NAME_LEN) "s", name);
    char password[PASSWORD_LEN+1];
    printf("Gimme your password: ");
    scanf("%" str(PASSWORD_LEN) "s", password);
    struct User *user = getUser(users, name, password);
    printUser(user);
    free(user);
    fclose(users);
}
```

and example sessions:

```
$ ./a.out
Gimme your username: root
Gimme your password: root
id: 1, user: root, password: root, isAdmin: 1
$ ./a.out
Gimme your username: root
Gimme your password: !root
```